# Upgrading Magento from 1.5.1.0 to latest stable release(1.6)

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

While upgrading my Magento store to it latest release through SSH, I'm not able to view the front as well as admin and getting error: "**Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists**"

After googling out and browsing through forums, I have deleted the cache by executing the following commands:
**rm -rf app/code/core/Zend/Cache var/cache/* var/session/***

So I have deleted all the cache as well as session data.But still the issue has not been resolved.Can anyone pls let me know, about how to proceed from here?

I'm following steps which are outlined here : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_1.5_to_1.6_upgrade

Comment: Are you using a database or memory based cache? In that case the configuration would still be present, even if the files in var/cache/ are deleted.

Comment: I'm a bit new to magento, but I've truncated the table "core_session". Are there any more tables to be truncated? Meanwhile when I do a chmod to 777 to all the files I'm able to login to the backend and see the version being updated in the footer... but when I changed them back to 644 the issue is back

Comment: It was file permission issue .... I have solved this by following the steps given on this http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions page and PHP ( DSO ) module.Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Just to have answer in the answer section:

It was file permission issue .... I have solved this by following the steps given on this magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions page and PHP ( DSO ) module.Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete an additional cache
    rm -rf /tmp/magento/var/cache/*